# SQLite trigger after insert

Tags: sql, sqlite, triggers

Please I need a help in SQLite trigger:
I want to fire the trigger after insert on a table and insert some values automatically into another table 
I have used this statement and it works but how can use it in a trigger

```
     INSERT INTO  student_score SELECT tk.cpr,s.Student_name, sum (sp.score), tk.test_taken_id
     FROM student s, student_paper sp,test_taken tk
     where s.cpr=tk.cpr
     and tk.test_taken_id=sp.test_taken_id
     group by tk.test_taken_id;
```

I hope that I explained clearly 
thank you

Comment: What prevents you from using this statement in a trigger if it works correctly?

Comment: If you don't tell us on what table you want the trigger, and how the data to be inserted in the trigger is related with the inserted data that caused the trigger to run, nobody can help you.

Comment: After insert on student_paper table

Comment: Post table structure for `student_paper`

Comment: CREATE TABLE Student_Paper(
Student_Answer Varchar Not NUll,
Score Integer null,
Question_ID Integer NOT NULL,
Test_taken_id Integer NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (Question_ID) REFERENCES addquestions(Question_ID ),
FOREIGN KEY (Test_taken_id) REFERENCES Test_taken (Test_taken_id))

Comment: demo to demostrate the same http://code2concept.blogspot.in/2015/02/android-sqlite-trigger-demo.html

Answer (score 2):

documentation here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html

```
CREATE TRIGGER customTrigger
AFTER INSERT ON student_score 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO newTable (col1, col2) VALUES ("value1", "value2")
END;
```

this should work. Do the necessary changes to fit your needs. Hope it helps, regards

Comment: Yes I know this way to create the trigger but I want to select the data from multiple tables and insert them into one table. I think I should use Insert Select statements

Comment: so you want to run the query that is in your question, inside a trigger?

Comment: yes, I want a trigger to do the query that I added afetr insert on test_paper table

Comment: I want a trigger to insert into a table called student_score using a trigger after insert on student_paper I have tried this insert statement witout a trigger and it works but I need the trigger to insert the data automatically. and the structure of student_score table is CREATE TABLE "Student_score" ("Student_ID" INTEGER, "Student_Name" VARCHAR, "Student_score" INTEGER, "taken_id" INTEGER, "subject" CHAR)

Comment: Is it possible to use WHERE condition somehow?