# How do I create a PostgreSQL TRIGGER to automatically calculate columns after INSERT?

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, triggers, sql-insert, sql-function

I am trying to populate some calculated columns after each new row `INSERT` in `PostgreSQL`, but I can't get it to work.

**I have already read these posts** (*I know these are for `SQLite` - this question was originally for `SQLite` but I have changed it to be for `PostgreSQL` - I will look at `SQLite` once I get `PG` version working*):

1. [sqlite-trigger-after-insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886507/sqlite-trigger-after-insert)
2. [sqlite-geopackage-after-insert-trigger-to-calculate-length-in-qgis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77856540/sqlite-geopackage-after-insert-trigger-to-calculate-length-in-qgis)

and

3. [PostgreSQL CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-triggers/creating-first-trigger-postgresql/)

but I want to know if I *have* to use a `SELECT` statement and the `FOR EACH ROW` statement within the `TRIGGER` because I ***only*** want to calculate values for the row just inserted, not all rows.

For more history, this question follows on from my previous question here:

- [how-do-i-create-a-permanent-stored-generated-calculated-computed-column-in-s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78078785/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-stored-generated-calculated-computed-column-in-s)

Here is the table setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    datetime TEXT,
    sys_id INT,
    cputil REAL,
    memfree REAL,
    sessnum INT,
    util_lag REAL,   -- to be calculated AFTER INSERT via TRIGGER
    mem_lag REAL,    -- to be calculated AFTER INSERT via TRIGGER
    util_diff REAL,  -- to be calculated AFTER INSERT via TRIGGER
    mem_diff REAL    -- to be calculated AFTER INSERT via TRIGGER
    util_change TEXT -- to be calculated AFTER INSERT via TRIGGER
);
```

Now for the `TRIGGER` setup.
I have tried the following SQL `TRIGGER` syntax, but I cannot get it to work:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_fill_calculated_columns
    AFTER INSERT ON myTable
BEGIN
    UPDATE myTable
        SET util_lag = LAG(cputil) OVER (ORDER BY datetime),
        SET mem_lag = LAG(memfree) OVER (ORDER BY datetime),
        SET util_diff = cputil - util_lag,
        SET mem_diff = memfree - mem_lag,
        SET util_change = CASE
            WHEN util_diff > 0 THEN 'Up'
            WHEN util_diff < 0 THEN 'Down'
    WHERE datetime = NEW.datetime AND sys_id = NEW.sys_id
END;
```

I have also tried the following (*which I think is closer to the way it needs to be done in `PostgreSQL`*):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_calculate_columns_after_insert
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
    AS $$
BEGIN
    NEW.util_lag := (SELECT LAG(cputil) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) FROM myTable);
    NEW.mem_lag := (SELECT LAG(memfree) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) FROM myTable);
    NEW.util_diff := cputil - util_lag;
    NEW.mem_diff := memfree - mem_lag;
    IF NEW.util_diff > 0 THEN
        NEW.util_change := 'Up';
    IF NEW.util_diff < 0 THEN
        NEW.util_change := 'Down';
    ELSE
        NEW.util_change := '';
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER tr_fill_calculated_columns
    AFTER INSERT ON myTable
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION fn_calculate_columns_after_insert();
```

No matter what I try I keep getting `SQL error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near ";"` or near some other character. This is driving me absolutely nuts. None of the official documentation or example tutorials give an example of exactly what I want to do, which I do not think is hard - update a simple calculated column based upon existing column values in a newly inserted row. Pretty basic in my view.

The full dataset contains hundreds of millions of rows, so performance is important - I only want the TRIGGER to calculate the last row immediately AFTER INSERT, and thereafter never query it again, that is, I only want the TRIGGER to act on the new row being inserted (each time a new row is inserted).

To help clarify exactly what I am looking for in the outcome, here is some sample PRE-TRIGGER data:

```
datetime,sys_id,cputil,memfree,sessnum
2019/05/03 08:06:14,100,0.57,0.51,47
2019/05/03 08:11:14,100,0.47,0.62,43
2019/05/03 08:16:14,100,0.56,0.57,62
2019/05/03 08:21:14,100,0.57,0.56,50
2019/05/03 08:26:14,100,0.35,0.46,43
2019/05/03 08:31:14,100,0.41,0.58,48
2019/05/03 08:36:14,100,0.57,0.35,58
2019/05/03 08:41:14,100,0.41,0.4,58
2019/05/03 08:46:14,100,0.53,0.35,62
2019/05/03 08:51:14,100,0.51,0.6,45
2019/05/03 08:56:14,100,0.32,0.37,47
2019/05/03 09:01:14,100,0.62,0.59,60
2019/05/03 09:06:14,100,0.66,0.72,57
2019/05/03 09:11:14,100,0.54,0.54,44
2019/05/03 09:16:14,100,0.29,0.4,47
2019/05/03 09:21:14,100,0.43,0.68,66
2019/05/03 09:26:14,100,0.49,0.66,65
2019/05/03 09:31:14,100,0.64,0.55,66
2019/05/03 09:36:14,100,0.42,0.6,42
2019/05/03 09:41:14,100,0.55,0.59,63
```

and here is a sample of the desired POST-TRIGGER result with calculated columns filled by the TRIGGER/FUNCTION:

```
datetime,sys_id,cputil,memfree,sessnum,util_lag,mem_lag,util_diff,mem_diff,util_change
2019/05/03 08:06:14,100,0.57,0.51,47,[NULL],[NULL],[NULL],[NULL],[NULL]
2019/05/03 08:11:14,100,0.47,0.62,43,0.57,0.51,-0.1,0.11,Down
2019/05/03 08:16:14,100,0.56,0.57,62,0.47,0.62,0.0900000000000001,-0.05,Up
2019/05/03 08:21:14,100,0.57,0.56,50,0.56,0.57,0.0099999999999999,-0.0099999999999999,Up
2019/05/03 08:26:14,100,0.35,0.46,43,0.57,0.56,-0.22,-0.1,Down
2019/05/03 08:31:14,100,0.41,0.58,48,0.35,0.46,0.06,0.12,Up
2019/05/03 08:36:14,100,0.57,0.35,58,0.41,0.58,0.16,-0.23,Up
2019/05/03 08:41:14,100,0.41,0.4,58,0.57,0.35,-0.16,0.05,Down
2019/05/03 08:46:14,100,0.53,0.35,62,0.41,0.4,0.12,-0.05,Up
2019/05/03 08:51:14,100,0.51,0.6,45,0.53,0.35,-0.02,0.25,Down
2019/05/03 08:56:14,100,0.32,0.37,47,0.51,0.6,-0.19,-0.23,Down
2019/05/03 09:01:14,100,0.62,0.59,60,0.32,0.37,0.3,0.22,Up
2019/05/03 09:06:14,100,0.66,0.72,57,0.62,0.59,0.04,0.13,Up
2019/05/03 09:11:14,100,0.54,0.54,44,0.66,0.72,-0.12,-0.18,Down
2019/05/03 09:16:14,100,0.29,0.4,47,0.54,0.54,-0.25,-0.14,Down
2019/05/03 09:21:14,100,0.43,0.68,66,0.29,0.4,0.14,0.28,Up
2019/05/03 09:26:14,100,0.49,0.66,65,0.43,0.68,0.06,-0.02,Up
2019/05/03 09:31:14,100,0.64,0.55,66,0.49,0.66,0.15,-0.11,Up
2019/05/03 09:36:14,100,0.42,0.6,42,0.64,0.55,-0.22,0.0499999999999999,Down
2019/05/03 09:41:14,100,0.55,0.59,63,0.42,0.6,0.13,-0.01,Up
```

Finally, I would like to know how to do this in SQLite too, i.e. what is the correct SQLite syntax to do exactly the same thing?

Comment: See documentation for [Trigger Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) and [Create Trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

Comment: Thanks, but the documentation is too confusing and lacks specific examples of what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In PL/pgSQL, the [`IF` conditional statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) requires a subsequent `END IF`. The error

   > ```
   > SQL error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near ";"`
   > ```

   was misleading because the parser was looking for that, found the nearest `END` which was the final one. It wanted an `END IF`, got an `END;` instead - hence the complaint.
2. You had missing parentheses in the signature.
3. The last semicolon in the function body is optional. The one right after it, is not optional.
4. You treated `NEW.x` and `x` interchangeably. The field is only defined within the scope of a query where it's a column in one of the source tables. Outside of it, you need to refer to the pseudo-record `NEW` and its fields.
5. You can use [PL/pgSQL `SELECT..INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW) to populate both variables at once (that's slightly different from [SQL `SELECT..INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html#id-1.9.3.173.7) which is a worse [`CREATE TABLE AS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html)).
6. Use `IF..ELSIF..ELSIF..END IF;` to specifically state what you want and when and avoid quietly handled *`null`* in `ELSE`.
7. This has to happen in a [`TRIGGER..`**`BEFORE`** `INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html#SUPPORTED-TRIGGER-TYPES). Doing this in an `AFTER` action you're not affecting the rows written into the table.
8. This doesn't do what you expect it to:

   ```sql
   NEW.util_lag := (SELECT LAG(cputil) OVER (ORDER BY datetime) FROM myTable);
   ```

   it attempts to select all rows from the table, and in each, show the value from the previous one. It tried to assign the entire, slightly shifted set of rows to the variable.
9. If you happen to insert an out-of-order row that'd squeeze in between two existing rows, it will get the correct values, but it would invalidate the one that was previously comparing against what is now 2 rows back. You might want to detect and handle this scenario as well as decrease the table and index [`fillfactor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#INDEX-RELOPTION-FILLFACTOR) adequately, to always have some room to "slide-in" the out-of-order rows and update the ones that they invalidate.
10. If you do large, multi-row inserts, a statement-level trigger should perform better - you could only fetch one last row from the table to start it off, then bulk-update the whole batch at once using the window function, the way you intially tried to.
11. Switch the `datetime` column to [`timestamptz`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME) type to save space, speed things up, index properly and enable adequate [functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html):

    ```sql
    ALTER TABLE myTable ALTER COLUMN datetime TYPE timestamptz
      USING (datetime::timestamptz);
    ```
12. If you're struggling with `timestamptz` input format, you can use [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING) with a specific mask: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zf0y1IrB)

    ```sql
    select to_timestamp('05.01.2010 15:08:44.997',
                        'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI:SS.MS');
    ```

    |  |
    | --- |
    | 2010-01-05 15:08:44.997+00 |

    or you can change your [`DateStyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting:

    ```sql
    set datestyle=ISO, DMY;
    select '13.01.2010 15:08:44.997'::timestamptz;
    ```

    |  |
    | --- |
    | 2010-01-13 15:08:44.997+00 |
13. Add an [index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html) on the `datetime` column, strap `cputil` and `memfree` fields to it as payload, increase its [`fillfactor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html#INDEX-RELOPTION-FILLFACTOR) from default 90 to 100%, then additionally [`CLUSTER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html) the table on it:

    ```sql
    CREATE INDEX dtidx ON myTable (datetime) 
      INCLUDE (cputil, memfree)
      WITH (fillfactor=100);
    ALTER TABLE myTable CLUSTER ON dtidx;
    ```

    That way, the query that's looking for the latest row doesn't need to touch the table and finds the values right in the index. Since you're only ever adding more and more recent rows, you don't need the 10% empty space in the index that's normally there to accommodate updates/deletes: both the table and the index will just keep *appending* new entries. `CLUSTER` tells the db the table is meant to be physically written in the order corresponding to the index - in your case that happens naturally, but declaring that explicitly might help some execution plans.
14. After some performance tests: `INCLUDE` might be unnecessary after all. It's doing an [index-only scan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html), but since the table's being written to, it has to do a heap fetch to make sure the index payload matches the actual values in the row. So you might as well let it do a regular index scan by removing the payload, which might get you some more performance thanks to decreasing the overall index size, similar to how `fillfactor` did it.
15. If you really only insert more recent rows, you can remove `WHERE datetime < NEW.datetime` - that way you'll just peek the most recent row from the table, removing the extra check and speeding things up a bit further. This breaks out-of-order inserts.

[Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/NQUithQ3)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_calculate_columns_after_insert()--missing parentheses here
    RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE PLPGSQL AS $f$
BEGIN
    SELECT     cputil, memfree 
    INTO NEW.util_lag, NEW.mem_lag
    FROM myTable 
    --this condition isn't necessary if you always insert more recent data
    --WHERE datetime < NEW.datetime 
    ORDER BY datetime DESC
    LIMIT 1;

    NEW.util_diff := NEW.cputil  - NEW.util_lag;
    NEW.mem_diff  := NEW.memfree - NEW.mem_lag;
    --the three cases explicitly say what you want and when
    --ELSE no longer assumes the same case for 0 and null
    --null is possible if there were any nulls involved earlier
    IF NEW.util_diff > 0 THEN
        NEW.util_change := 'Up';
    ELSIF NEW.util_diff < 0 THEN
        NEW.util_change := 'Down';
    ELSIF NEW.util_diff = 0 THEN
        NEW.util_change := '';
    END IF;--this was missing
    RETURN NEW;
END;--This semicolon is optional because it's immediately followed by closing dollar qoutes.
$f$;--This semicolon was missing. It is not optional, because it ends the whole `create function` statement

CREATE TRIGGER tr_fill_calculated_columns
    BEFORE INSERT ON myTable
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION fn_calculate_columns_after_insert();
```

Here's what it comes up with if you try to insert your sample batch:

| datetime | sys_id | cputil | memfree | sessnum | util_lag | mem_lag | util_diff | mem_diff | util_change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2019/05/03 08:06:14 | 100 | 0.57 | 0.51 | 47 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |
| 2019/05/03 08:11:14 | 100 | 0.47 | 0.62 | 43 | 0.57 | 0.51 | -0.099999994 | 0.110000014 | Down |
| 2019/05/03 08:16:14 | 100 | 0.56 | 0.57 | 62 | 0.47 | 0.62 | 0.09 | -0.050000012 | Up |
| 2019/05/03 08:21:14 | 100 | 0.57 | 0.56 | 50 | 0.56 | 0.57 | 0.00999999 | -0.00999999 | Up |
| 2019/05/03 08:26:14 | 100 | 0.35 | 0.46 | 43 | 0.57 | 0.56 | -0.22 | -0.099999994 | Down |

Performance test on 220k rows:

| No index | index | index..include | index..include..fillfactor | index..fillfactor | removed `where` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| >30s (doesn't finish) | [9.7s](https://dbfiddle.uk/KT5IM1r1) | [8.4s](https://dbfiddle.uk/VCG0qPLt) | [8.5s](https://dbfiddle.uk/hjIw4HeJ) | [8.1s](https://dbfiddle.uk/WQ1vFsdw) | 7.4s |

Comment: Thank you! I am working through each of your points to understand them...

Comment: Pts 1-3 & 6: thx for clarifying. My syntax errors there.

Comment: Pt5: `SELECT ... INTO ...` I understand creates a new table - is this just transient (in memory) for calculation and then the results go into the original table? I was hoping to avoid using `SELECT ...` if possible, but I may have an incorrect understanding of how that works or the functional limitations (which may require it here?)

Comment: Pt8: yeah, I definitely do not want to select or iterate over all rows each time a single new row is inserted. I my first example, I had `SET util_lag = LAG(cputil) OVER (ORDER BY datetime)` which more accurately conveyed my intent.

Comment: Pt9: in theory, new rows should never be inserted out of order as it is real time timeseries data being inserted as the data becomes available. I think I see your point. This is why I am trying to ensure correct sorting upon TABLE initialization - the table will be created once, then populated once with all available data the first time, and it will thereafter simply be maintained as each new row becomes available by being inserted (with calculated fields) as it happens (in real time + system latency).

Comment: Pt 10: this will only ever happen once, when the table is populated for the very first time immediately after creation. So I don't expect this to really be a problem.

Comment: Pt11: the real source data for the datetime column comes (at this stage) in the form of a text string formatted as "DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm:ss.uuu", e.g. "05.01.2010 15:08:44.997" - i.e. Jan 5th 2010, 3:08PM and 44.997 seconds past the minute. I wrestled a bit with how to 'tell' PostgreSQL how to 'read' the incoming data as a timestamp. I will play with your suggestion and see if it is a better way (I get that it may save on space due to encoding).

Comment: I am a little confused by `ORDER BY datetime DESC`, but is it `LIMIT 1` that stops the `SELECT` from iterating through all rows and causes it to just return the most recently inserted row (due to the `DESC` order)?

Comment: This use of `select..into` doesn’t create a table, just spits out the two fields straight into the two variables. `order by datetime desc limit 1` goes to the index which tells it which row’s the most recent, then it grabs that row - it’s possible to configure the index to already hold the two fields, avoiding a heap fetch. The timestamp format is dictated by your locale, but you can also set up a mask in `to_timestamp()`. I’ll add an example later

Comment: Thank you. I've been out all afternoon, but am back now continuing to work through your code. I am currently inserting rows 1 by 1 and viewing the output to check everything. Should be done in the next 2-3 hours. You are a champion and if this solves my problem, I will definitely be giving you the bounty. I very much appreciate your help.

Comment: I hope you got the points...never awarded a bounty before.

Comment: @skeetastax I did, thanks. While I appreciate that, it's better to leave the bounty up for its full duration: that way you would attract more people, more feedback, more answers, more ideas and remarks. I was going to add an example of a statement-level trigger but I think it makes sense to conclude the thread here, leaving it focused on just the row-level approach. And if you're curious, you can open a separate, regular thread (no bounty, just link it here), about how to convert this row-level trigger into a statement-level version.

Comment: Well now you have doubly earned it! Thank you for the good advice :) I didn't even think of the bounty lifetime - will have to lookup how long they last. I might create another question later as you suggest, but for the moment I need to apply this to my real dataset and see how it goes.

Comment: I don't suppose you have an SQLite version too? It seems quite different, and the result from https://codeconverter.io/convert/postgresql-to-sqlite does not work...

Comment: @skeetastax SQLite triggers work a bit differently: you'd have to either set up a view and add an `instead of` trigger that redirects and modifies inserts to the table, or find and update the row you inserted `after` the fact. You can take this Postgres trigger, wipe the comments and post a question showing it along with your attempt to translate to SQLite, on `sqlite` tag. You can drop me a link here and I'll give that a shot, too.

Comment: @skeetastax [Here's](https://dbfiddle.uk/mtPVH6Gv) the SQLite approach with re-routed `view` and a bootstrap row, [here's](https://dbfiddle.uk/bJo98Rdn) one with an `after` trigger that updates the inserted row compared to what's now second-but-last, using SQLite `limit 1,1` (PostgreSQL `limit 1 offset 1` or `offset 1 fetch first row only`).

Comment: I posted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78171074/how-do-i-create-a-sqlite-trigger-to-automatically-calculate-columns-after-insert?noredirect=1#comment137815438_78171074